# Sum all columns with replacing 0 as 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am generating monthly attendance of students. And in the last column, I am displaying Total classes in the format of -

(Total classes attended)/(Total class held)

So, sum() will give me the total classes attended but how do I get total classes held as attendance can be any integer between 0 to 4 ?

**Sample Data of Attendance Table :-**

```
+--------------+-------------+----------+------------+------------+-----------+
| EnrollmentNo | SubjectCode |   Date   | Attendance | CourseCode | FacultyId |
+--------------+-------------+----------+------------+------------+-----------+
| DDU-123/45   | CSHT101     | 2/1/2018 |          0 | BSCCS      | Fac101    |
| DDU-123/45   | CSHT102     | 2/1/2018 |          1 | BSCCS      | Fac101    |
| DDU-123/45   | CSHT203     | 2/1/2018 |          1 | BSCCS      | Fac101    |
| DDU-123/45   | CSHT101     | 2/2/2018 |          1 | BSCCS      | Fac101    |
| DDU-123/45   | CSHT102     | 2/2/2018 |          1 | BSCCS      | Fac101    |
| DDU-123/45   | CSHT203     | 2/2/2018 |          1 | BSCCS      | Fac101    |
| DDU-123/45   | CSHT101     | 2/3/2018 |          2 | BSCCS      | Fac101    |
| DDU-123/45   | CSHT102     | 2/3/2018 |          1 | BSCCS      | Fac101    |
| DDU-123/45   | CSHT203     | 2/3/2018 |          1 | BSCCS      | Fac101    |
| DDU-123/45   | CSHT101     | 2/5/2018 |          1 | BSCCS      | Fac101    |
| DDU-123/45   | CSHT102     | 2/5/2018 |          0 | BSCCS      | Fac101    |
| DDU-123/45   | CSHT203     | 2/5/2018 |          1 | BSCCS      | Fac101    |
+--------------+-------------+----------+------------+------------+-----------+
```

**Sample Data of Student Table :-**

```
+--------------+--------+-------------+------------+------+
| EnrollmentNo | RollNo | CollegeCode | CourseCode | Year |
+--------------+--------+-------------+------------+------+
| DDU-123/45   |     38 | DDUC        | BSCCS      | 2012 |
+--------------+--------+-------------+------------+------+
```

**Sample Data of UserDetails Table :-**

```
+--------------+-----------+----------+--------+---------+---------+
| EnrollmentNo | FirstName | LastName | Gender | Address |  Phone  |
+--------------+-----------+----------+--------+---------+---------+
| DDU-123/45   | Suyash    | Gupta    | Male   | Lucknow | 9817271 |
+--------------+-----------+----------+--------+---------+---------+
```

**Output :-**

[image: Output]

In the output, Total column should contain **4/5** instead of 4/4.

Below is the code where I am generating monthly attendance.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_ATTENDANCE_REPORT_FOR_FACULTY
@startdate DATE,  
@enddate DATE,
@collegecode nvarchar(10),
@coursecode nvarchar(10),
@subjectcode nvarchar(10)
  
AS BEGIN

DECLARE @query as varchar(MAX);

with cte (startdate) as 
(
    select @startdate startdate
    union all 
    select dateadd(DD, 1, startdate) 
    from cte
    where startdate < @enddate
)

select @query = coalesce(@query, '') + 
              N',coalesce(MAX(CASE when A.[Date] = ''' + 
              cast(cte.startdate as nvarchar(20)) + 
              N''' THEN Convert(varchar(10),A.[Attendance]) end), ''-'') ' + 
              quotename(convert(char(2), cte.startdate,104))
from cte
where datename(weekday, cte.startdate) <> 'Sunday';

set @query = 'Select S.RollNo AS [Roll No],Concat(FirstName,'' '',LastName) Name' + @query + ',Concat(sum(Attendance),''/'',count(Attendance)) Total
              from Attendance A, Student S, UserDetails U
              where A.EnrollmentNo=S.EnrollmentNo and S.EnrollmentNo=U.userID and S.CollegeCode=''' + @collegecode + ''' and A.CourseCode=''' + @coursecode + ''' and A.SubjectCode =''' + @subjectcode +''' 
              and A.Date between ''' + Convert(nvarchar,@startdate) + ''' and ''' + Convert(nvarchar,@enddate) + '''
              Group By S.RollNo,U.FirstName,U.LastName';
            

Execute (@query)
END
```

DDL and Consumable Sample Data *(Courtesy of Larnu)*:

```
CREATE TABLE #Attendance (EnrollmentNo varchar(10),
                          SubjectCode varchar(7),
                          [Date] date,
                          Attendence tinyint,
                          CourseCode varchar(5),
                          FacultyId varchar(6));

INSERT INTO #Attendance
VALUES ('DDU-123/45','CSHT101','20180201',0,'BSCCS','Fac101'),
       ('DDU-123/45','CSHT102','20180201',1,'BSCCS','Fac101'),
       ('DDU-123/45','CSHT203','20180201',1,'BSCCS','Fac101'),
       ('DDU-123/45','CSHT101','20180202',1,'BSCCS','Fac101'),
       ('DDU-123/45','CSHT102','20180202',1,'BSCCS','Fac101'),
       ('DDU-123/45','CSHT203','20180202',1,'BSCCS','Fac101'),
       ('DDU-123/45','CSHT203','20180203',1,'BSCCS','Fac101'),
       ('DDU-123/45','CSHT101','20180205',1,'BSCCS','Fac101'),
       ('DDU-123/45','CSHT102','20180205',0,'BSCCS','Fac101'),
       ('DDU-123/45','CSHT203','20180205',1,'BSCCS','Fac101');

CREATE TABLE #Student (EnrollmentNo varchar(10),
                       RollNo smallint,
                       CollegeCode varchar(4),
                       CourseCode varchar(5),
                       [year] int);
INSERT INTO #Student
VALUES ('DDU-123/45',38,'DDUC','BSCCS',2012);

CREATE TABLE #UserDetail (EnrollmentNo varchar(10),
                          Firstname varchar(50),
                          LastName varchar(50),
                          Gender varchar (6),
                          [Address] varchar(500),
                          Phone varchar(15));
INSERT INTO #UserDetail
VALUES ('DDU-123/45','Suyash','Gupta','Male','Lucknow',9817271);
GO
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected output?

Comment: You also should start using ANSI-92 style joins. They have been around for more than 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins And that dynamic sql is pretty scary. You can parameterize dynamic sql to help prevent against sql injection.

Comment: @uzi Updated the sample data and output!!

Comment: You will have to plug the holes in your range with dummy data. The report is not calculating the 4th month as it does not exist in the dataset.

Comment: @RossBush It's not about the month. I am generating the attendance of February month in the output.

Comment: @RossBush I *think* those are Americanised dates: 2/5/2018 = 05 February 2018. Hence why it goes up to 28 (28 days in that month). To the OP, when providing dates, please ensure you provide them in a non-ambiguous format. 03/02/2017 can have multiple values. The "best" is generally yyyy-MM-dd or yyyyMMdd (2018-02-12 & 20180212 for today's date).

Comment: The inner join with attendance will omit months with no activity, right? So month 1-5 joined on attendance will only pull back 4 months even though the range is over 5 months.

Comment: @RossBush It's not over any kind of months. That data is for the first 5 days of February. Those are Americanised dates.

Comment: @RossBush 1-5 are dates, not months. Date is in the 'mm/dd/yyyy' format.

Comment: I think you just need to change `count(Attendance)` to `sum(case when SubjectCode = ''CSHT101'' then Attendance end)` in your query

Comment: @SuyashGupta - Ah, and the 4th is a Sunday.

Comment: @SuyashGupta Crate a view with dummy column for  Attendance where you can replace all the 0 by 1 using switch or if statement, then replace `Concat(sum(Attendance),''/'',count(Attendance)` with `Concat(sum(Attendance),''/'',count(dummy_Attendance)`

Comment: @uzi sum(Attendance) will give me only the classes attended. That will not include the '0' which I really want. I want '0' to be summed as '1' in the denominator of Total column.

Comment: @PraveenDA Thank you! I can always do that. But is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: So, instead do: `SUM(CASE Attendance WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE Attendance END)`

Comment: @Larnu Thank you, such a simple solution and I couldn't think of it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is such a simple solution (Courtesy Larnu).

```
SUM(CASE Attendance WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE Attendance END)
```